# The meaning of port 0 in netstat output

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

What is the meaning of port 0 in netstat -an output in Windows? I'm asking about socket in Foreign address column:

0.0.0.0:0

I know that 0.0.0.0 address means, that host is listening on all interfaces, but what is the function of port zero?

Comment: Analogous IPv6: http://superuser.com/questions/661188/what-is-in-the-local-address-of-netstat-output/802793#802793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see this as the "Foreign" address, the meaning is slightly different – it's not about the interface; that would be the "Local" address.

All zeros in the "Foreign" column just mean that there is *no* remote address yet. The line represents a *listening* socket, which will accept connections from any address, any port. Those connections would be displayed as separate lines.

(From what I remember, in some early systems it used to be possible to create TCP sockets that would only accept connections *from* a specific host, a specific port, or both.)

Comment: So to sum up: port 0 means ANY port?

Comment: Yes. In the Foreign address, 0:0 means any remote host, any remote port. (Just to remind: this column is not about local interfaces.)

Comment: @RZR A TCP listening socket or any UDP socket will basically always be listening for connections or datagrams *from* any port.

Comment: … although a `connect()` on a UDP/IP socket will change this behaviour.